# Poco based smtp client and ssl Connection

Tags: c++, ssl, smtp, smtpclient, poco-libraries

I'am attempting to develop an Email client.
i'm just starting.
My problem is about SSL connection with the c++ lib Poco

here is some code:

```
  std::string mailhost("smtp.gmail.com");
  std::string recipient("xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
  std::string sender("rushmab@gmail.com");
  std::string response;
  try
    {
      Poco::Net::SSLManager &app = Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance();
      Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
      Poco::Net::MailMessage message;
      message.setSender(sender);
      message.addRecipient(Poco::Net::MailRecipient(Poco::Net::MailRecipient::PRIMARY_RECIPIENT, recipient));
      message.setSubject("Hello from the POCO C++ Libraries");
      std::string content;
      content += "Hello ";
      content += recipient;
      content += ",\r\n\r\n";
      content += "This is a greeting from the POCO C++ Libraries.\r\n\r\n";
      message.addContent(new Poco::Net::StringPartSource(content));
      Poco::Net::SecureSMTPClientSession session(mailhost);
     session.login();
     session.startTLS();
      session.login(Poco::Net::SMTPClientSession::AUTH_LOGIN, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxx");
      session.sendMessage(message);
      session.close();
    } catch (Poco::Exception& exc) {
    std::cerr << exc.displayText() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
```

here is the output

```
Illegal state: An application configuration is required to initialize the Poco::Net::SSLManager, but no Poco::Util::Application instance is available.
```

Thank You

Comment: Did you run this from a Poco::Application instance? The error seems to indicate that you didn't

Comment: i don't find in the doc how to use this class, or i did'nt understand it...

Comment: You'll need to either initialize the client side of the SSLManager (SSLManager:initializeClient) or use the Util:Application.

Comment: Related answers with examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11998973/1247192