# Poco stops after SMTPClientSession.login

Tags: c++, email, poco-libraries

I just started with the Poco library and tried to create an email program (Which I knew virtually nothing about). The following is my code (There may be other problems with it besides the one I've encountered so far, but I just started working on it)

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Poco::Net::SocketAddress add("smtp.gmail.com:465");
    Poco::Net::StreamSocket sock(add);
    Poco::Net::SMTPClientSession sess(sock);
    std::cout << "-";
    sess.login(
            "gmail.com",
            Poco::Net::SMTPClientSession::AUTH_LOGIN,
            "----",
            "----"
    );
    Poco::Net::MailMessage msg;
    Poco::Net::MailRecipient resp(Poco::Net::MailRecipient::PRIMARY_RECIPIENT,"michaelrgoldfine@gmail.com");
    msg.addRecipient(resp);
    std::string content("HELP SOS");
    msg.encodeWord(content);
    std::cout << msg.getContent() << "-";
}
```

When I go into the debugger, it runs fine until it gets to sess.login then suddenly the little bar that represents were I am in the code disappears but the program keeps running (I'm not experienced enough to know what that means). None of the cout stuff I put in actually prints, the debugger just goes past that line but nothing shows up. After a little while this comes up:

```
terminate called throwing an exception
```

So what's going on?

Comment: For the output to show up, use `std::flush` to flush the buffers, or `std::endl` if you want newline too.

Comment: Thanks. Why does the Buffer not flush automatically?

Comment: Because it's buffered... :) It's a speed issue, outputting every character each time is not effective. You have to fill it up before it's flushed automatically. And no, I do not know the size of the buffer, it depends om implementation and is not (to my knowledge) not specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to use SMTP over TLS (the port 465 passed to the `SocketAddress`). In one shot you have to learn (1) TLS and certificate handling in POCO, before focusing on (2) your goal: sending an email message.

I suggest to start learning POCO with simpler examples. You can find sample code in the various `samples` directories in the POCO source code.

I think that your code is just hanging on the TLS handshake, because it doesn't know what to do.

These are the fixes you should do **before** looking at the solution:

1. Place your code inside a `try/catch` block. POCO uses exceptions.
2. Replace `StreamSocket` with [`SecureStreamSocket`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SecureStreamSocket.html).
3. The simplest way to properly initialize `SecureStreamSocket` is via the `Application` class. See the [Applications](http://pocoproject.org/slides/190-Applications.pdf) slides and `Util/samples/SampleApp/src/SampleApp.cpp`.
4. See the documentation for the [`SSLManager`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SSLManager.html) for how to properly tell the Application which certificates to use.
5. Don't specify an hostname to the `login()` method. The hostname is optional and should be the client hostname, not the server (See the SMTP RFC).
6. Remember to actually send the message! Your code is not sending it :-)

OK, and now for the running code. I left steps 4 and 6 as an exercise, but this code will at least run the TLS handshake, will tell you that it cannot verify the server's certificate and, if you answer Yes on the terminal to the questions on the certificates, it will fail the SMTP authentication.

```
class MiniApp : public Poco::Util::Application {
    int main(const vector <string>& args) {
        try {
            Poco::Net::SocketAddress add("smtp.gmail.com:465");
            Poco::Net::SecureStreamSocket sock(add);
            Poco::Net::SMTPClientSession session(sock);
            session.login(Poco::Net::SMTPClientSession::AUTH_LOGIN, "user", "pw");
            Poco::Net::MailMessage msg;
            Poco::Net::MailRecipient recipient(Poco::Net::MailRecipient::PRIMARY_RECIPIENT,
                                    "michaelrgoldfine@gmail.com");
            msg.addRecipient(recipient);
            string content("HELP SOS");
            msg.encodeWord(content);
        } catch (Poco::Exception& e) {
            cout << "Error: " << e.displayText() << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
};

POCO_APP_MAIN(MiniApp)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what headers do I need to run it?

Comment: The documentation of each class mentions which header to include.

For example for `SecureSMTPClientSession`[1] it says to include `<Poco/Net/SecureSMTPClientSession.h>` and to link against the POCO NetSSL library.

[1]: http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SecureSMTPClientSession.html

Comment: Creating an application instead of a function to send a mail seems to be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, so I struggled with login(), trying to use smtp.gmail.com. This is the excerpt of the communication with the SSL session that made it work.

```
string host("smtp.gmail.com")
Poco::UInt16 port = 587;

SecureSMTPClientSession session(host, port);

session.open();

Poco::Net::initializeSSL();

SharedPtr<InvalidCertificateHandler> ptrHandler = new AcceptCertificateHandler(false);

Context::Ptr ptrContext = new Context(Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "", Context::VERIFY_RELAXED, 9, true, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");

SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(0, ptrHandler, ptrContext);

try
{
  // SSL
  session.login();
  if (session.startTLS(ptrContext))
  {
    session.login(SMTPClientSession::AUTH_LOGIN, "user@gmail.com", "yourpassword");
    session.sendMessage(message);
  }
  session.close();
  Poco::Net::uninitializeSSL();
}
catch (SMTPException &e)
{
  cout << e.message() << endl;
  session.close();
  Poco::Net::uninitializeSSL();
  return 0;
}
```

Original source:

http://www.axistasoft.sg/tutorials/cpp/poco/item/sending-email-messages-using-smtp-protocol

Comment: Are you using `password` as cleartext? My code is quite exactly the same as yours and I get an exception with `Login using LOGIN password failed: 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257`

Comment: Google's 2-step-verification was the reason ;-) Works great now!

Comment: I built Poco for Mac, but I cannot find `SecureSMTPClientSession.h` in `Net`. Any idea?

Comment: For anyone that this is not working, google has introduced a new setting in security that is turned off by default. It's called "Access for less secure apps" as of this time. Turn that on and it will work with the above code. I wasted a whole day due to this issue. Hope it helps someone.