# Unable to verify server certificate through Poco

Tags: c++, ssl, client, poco

I'm trying to implement certificate verification in my client.
I'm always getting `SSL Exception: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed after 893ms` and I'm sure it is valid, tried getting google.com this way and failed. I am using RejectCertificateHandler because the documentation states:

> A RejectCertificateHandler is invoked whenever an error occurs
>   verifying the certificate. It always rejects the certificate.
>
> A AcceptCertificateHandler is invoked whenever an error occurs
>   verifying the certificate. It always accepts the certificate. Should
>   be using for testing purposes only.

What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> pAcceptCertHandler = new Poco::Net::RejectCertificateHandler(true);

Poco::Net::Context::Ptr pContext = new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "", Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_RELAXED, 9, false, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(NULL, pAcceptCertHandler, pContext);

Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), pContext);
std::string path(uri.getPathAndQuery());

Poco::Net::HTTPRequest request(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, path, Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
initializeHttpGetRequest(request);
session.sendRequest(request);
session.setKeepAlive(true);

Poco::Timespan timespan(0, 0, 10, 0, 0);
session.setKeepAliveTimeout(timespan);

Poco::Net::HTTPResponse res;
std::istream & is = session.receiveResponse(res);

responseCode = res.getStatus();
```

Comment: I recommend either inhering `InvalidCertificateHandler` and show us the output, or using `ConsoleCertificateHandler` and show us the output. This would help us answer your question. Either way, the problem is in the verification, and it might be the cipher list you use.

Comment: `WARNING: Certificate verification failed
----------------------------------------
Issuer Name:  /C=IE/O=Baltimore/OU=CyberTrust/CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Subject Name: /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA`

The certificate yielded the error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: You probably don't have Digicert as a trusted root authority in your machine. If it's Windows we're talking about, have a look at `certmgr.msc`. I believe that is your problem.

Comment: Or easier - open this link in Chrome or IE (not firefox, as it uses its own certificate management) - https://ev-root.digicert.com/, and see if it yields errors.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, have checked it on another machine but it would suck if everybody would have to trust it manually.

Comment: Web page loaded fine `If your browser loads this page without warning, it trusts the DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA Certificate. EV indication should also be active if supported by your browser.`

Comment: Which browser did you use?

Comment: Safari and Chrome, both say it is ok.

Comment: That site was useless. Tried finding you a site with that exact certificate, but couldn't. It's still that problem though. I'll try finding a better solution later.

Comment: Maybe I should build OpenSSL with certificates bundled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble getting POCO HTTPSClientSession to send a request - certificate verify failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354101/trouble-getting-poco-httpsclientsession-to-send-a-request-certificate-verify-f)

Comment: It's not self-signed and I'm hitting the right domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further research I've found out, that the built in OpenSSL with Mac OS doesn't have any CA certificate bundled (it doesn't use those inside the system Keychain). So whatever host you try to verify, fails even if the certificate is valid.

I've exported those CA certificates into a single .pem file and bundled it with my application.

Now when I create a context I use this method:

```
NSString *rootCA = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"rootCA.pem"];
Poco::Net::Context::Ptr pContext = new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", [rootCA UTF8String], verificationMode, 9, false, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
```

Comment: Still helpful, after all these years. Thank you.